Limit and sum interchange
By wrinting $e^t=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}$ and using the interchanging theorem of limit and sum (the obtained series is uniformly convergent in $\mathbb{R}_+$, because $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}$ converges normally on $\mathbb{R}$ and $e^{-t}\leq1$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$) we obtain
$$\lim_{t\to+\infty}e^{-t}e^t=\lim_{t\to+\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}e^{-t}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}e^{-t}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}0=0$$
where I'm wrong ?

If you want to apply the Weierstrass M-test, then you need a bound on the functions which you are summing, and not the sum itself. You'd need a bound like $t^n/n!\leq M_n$ on the positive real line, where the sum of all the $M_n$'s is finite.

We have these conditions because we have power series of radius of convergence $=+\infty$.

Weierstrass M-test needs 2 conditions: A. Each $t^n/n!$ is bounded. B. The sum of bounds (not $t^n/n!$) converges. What you said neither A nor B, and here A is violated.

Thank you Simon and Y.D.X. It is true that I have a power series of radius of convergence $+\infty$, but this gives the normally convergence on any bounded disc and then the uniform convergence on any bounded disc and not on $\mathbb{R}$
